# Cypress doesn't work with an external login

Tags: authentication, cypress, e2e-testing, e2e

I'm working on e2e test with cypress on my application.
In my case the login are manage by a external service.
When I want to enter in my application's home page (https://myApplication/home), the system redirects me in different superdomains to login.
At first cypress seems to be able to change the superdomain, but once arrived in external service page for the authentication, the system go in login error (as if we have already logged in, but incorrect).
This type of behavior does not happen outside the cypress .

Are there alternative solutions to manage external access in a cypress test or is it possible to manage it directly from cypress?

I added in my cypress.json the chromeWebSecurity:false and when I call the link for login, I added the failOnStatusCode: false,
but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is caused by SameSite cookie blocking , then I've just been fighting the same issue. I resolved it by intercepting all requests, checking if they had a set-cookie header(s) and rewriting the SameSite attribute. There's probably a neater way to do it, as this does clutter up the cypress dashboard a little.

Sadly Zachary Costa's answer no longer works as Chrome 94 removed the `SameSiteByDefaultCookies` flag.

You can add this as a command for easy reuse:

In your commands file:

```ts
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions(): void;
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions', () => {
  cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      if (!res.headers['set-cookie']) {
        return;
      }

      const disableSameSite = (headerContent: string): string => {
        return headerContent.replace(/samesite=(lax|strict)/ig, 'samesite=none');
      }

      if (Array.isArray(res.headers['set-cookie'])) {
        res.headers['set-cookie'] = res.headers['set-cookie'].map(disableSameSite);
      } else {
        res.headers['set-cookie'] = disableSameSite(res.headers['set-cookie']);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Usage:

```ts
  it('should login using third party idp', () => {
    cy.disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions();
    //add test body here
  });
```

or alteratively, run it before each test:

```ts
  beforeEach(() => cy.disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions());
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of 2022!
(although it's extremely hacky ;-))

Answer (score 1):

We were encountering a similar issue, where Cypress was redirecting us to the default "You are not logged in" page after getting through the login process. I'm not certain if that's EXACTLY the issue you were experiencing, but just in case, here's our solution. In our case, the issue was caused by Chrome's "Same Site Cookies" feature interacting poorly with Cypress, so we needed to disable it. In your `plugins/index.js` file, you would add the following code:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      launchOptions.args.push('--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies');
    }
    return launchOptions;
  });
};
```

Note that if you already have launchOptions being set, you can just add this code onto it so it doesn't clash at all.

Hopefully, this works for you as well!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I followed your solution but I still have the problem. 
Did you also have the login managed by an identity manager / provider for your case?

I also tried to visit the identity manager / provider url directly (with cy.visit ()), in this case I can enter username and password for login, but when cypress clicks on submit, the system returns the message "The The logout procedure was completed safely and successfully! ", As if I had performed the logout procedure and not the login.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of cypress you can't go to another domain in the same test. This is due to the fact that cypress injects its test into the browser (they are working on this issue).

So one solution today is that you need to utilize cy.request to perform the login programmatically and inject the auth secret (jwt, cookie, localstorage, token or what you have) into the browser context yourself (for cookie this would be cy.setcookie).

Always make sure to checkout the plugins if there is already an abstraction for your login. Often this is openId or ntlm.