# Testing React Google Login with Cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress, google-signin

I'm testing in `localhost:3000` the `react-google-login` with `cypress-social-logins`.
I'm following the basic recipe:

```
describe('Login', () => {
  it('Login through Google', () => {
    const username = Cypress.env('googleSocialLoginUsername')
    const password = Cypress.env('googleSocialLoginPassword')
    const loginUrl = Cypress.env('loginUrl')
    const cookieName = Cypress.env('cookieName')
    const socialLoginOptions = {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      loginUrl: loginUrl,
      headless: true,
      logs: false,
      loginSelector: '[href="/auth/auth0/google-oauth2"]',
      postLoginSelector: '.account-panel'
    }

    return cy.task('GoogleSocialLogin', socialLoginOptions).then(({cookies}) => {
      cy.clearCookies()

      const cookie = cookies.filter(cookie => cookie.name === cookieName).pop()
      if (cookie) {
        cy.setCookie(cookie.name, cookie.value, {
          domain: cookie.domain,
          expiry: cookie.expires,
          httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly,
          path: cookie.path,
          secure: cookie.secure
        })

        Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
          preserve: cookieName
        })
      }
    })
  })
})
```

EDIT: I just saw that it actually does not load the login page:

`http://localhost:3000/signin`

does not go there and waits for the selector.
Any idea of which can be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress doesn't work with an external login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561394/cypress-doesnt-work-with-an-external-login)

Comment: Thanks but no. Now I saw that the plugin does not load the page "http://localhost:3000/signin". any idea? Thanks

Comment: I just noticed that if you set headless: false it actually opens the webiste, but does not do anythig else